# Java Time(4,129) should give 6 hours and 9 minutes

Tags: java

I have a problem with a program that will tell the time. For example if you ask java what Time(4,129)is, the output should give 6 hours and 9 minutes(Because 129 minute can be simplfied.

Note: This is just a part of my code. I know my code will fail for minute values such as 120,180.

I do understand my forloop is inefficient, but that is not the problem. My problem is that my output for Time(4,129) gives me 4 hours and -51  minutes which is wrong. It should be 6 hours and 9 minutes.

**How I think the code is working:**

1. We enter the forloop, go to if statement,check if 129%60  is greater than 0 (9>0) which is true, then proceed.

   2.For the body of the if statement, minutes will reduce  from 129 to 69 and increment hours by 1 (It is now 5 hours). Forloop ends.

   3. We repeat our forloop which is the 2nd iteration. Check if statement condition ,69%60>0 --> 9>0,True, go to if statement body.
   4. minutes will change to 9 from 69 minutes and hours increment by 1. If statement ends.
   5. Repeat if statement, Third iteration, 9%60 is false therefor if statement does not run.

---

```
Time(int x, int y) {
        hours = x;
        minutes = y;
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            int temp;

            if (minutes % 60 > 0) {
                minutes = minutes - 60;
                hours = hours++;
```

Comment: `System.out.println(Duration.ofHours(4).plusMinutes(129));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Repeat if statement, 9%60 is false therefor if statement does not run

Is it? For `minutes` being `9`, `minutes % 60` is `9`, which is greater than `0`. You want `minutes > 59`, no modulo needed.

But even easier: `hours += minutes / 60; minutes %= 60`. No loop required.

Comment: You know how `x += 5` is same as `x = x + 5` (more or less)? `minutes %= 60` means `minutes = minutes % 60`.

Comment: Thanks, i got it. Question: Say you have a double 10.20 and you want the number "20" in 10.20. what code will allow me to do that?

Comment: `x - (int) x` should do. (As long as `x` is not negative.)

Comment: How about 10.20mod1? gives .20 then we times it by 100

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why you use a loop. But if you insist, how about

```
while (minutes >= 60) {
  minutes -= 60;
  hours += 1;
}
```

Your analysis for the final loop is wrong. 9 % 60 is 9. That's greater than 0 so minutes becomes -51.

Answer (score 0):

This will yield the correct result, the flaw in your code is the use of modulo to figure out when the minutes should be taken into account:

```
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        int x = 4;
        int y = 129;
        int hours = x;
        int minutes = y;
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            int temp;

            if (minutes > 59) {
                minutes = minutes - 60;
                hours = ++hours;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Hours: "+ hours + " minutes: " + minutes);
}
}
```